# How to solve E/error: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, retrofit2

When I try to call rest API in the android studio I get an error that:

> E/error: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

I use firebase for the database and retrofit2 library.

But when I call the values a go to the firebase database and call the onFailure in call.enqueue() method.

```
public class APis {
    public static final String URL = "http://192.168.178.43:8081/api/";

    public static userService setuser() {
        return client.getClient(URL).create(userService.class);
    }
}


public interface userService {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("signup")
    Call<userlog> adduser(@Body userlog userlog);
}

public class userlog {

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String emial_;

    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password_;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name_;

    public userlog() {
    }

    public userlog(String emial_, String password, String name_) {
        this.emial_ = emial_;
        this.password_ = password;
        this.name_ = name_;
    }

    public String getEmial_() {
        return emial_;
    }

    public void setEmial_(String emial_) {
        this.emial_ = emial_;
    }

    public String getPassword_() {
        return password_;
    }

    public void setPassword_(String password_) {
        this.password_ = password_;
    }

    public String getName_() {
        return name_;
    }

    public void setName_(String name_) {
        this.name_ = name_;
    }
}

    public void setPassword_(String password_) {
        this.password_ = password_;
    }

}




   private void adduser_(userlog userll) {

        service = APis.setuser();
        Call<userlog> call = service.adduser(userll);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<userlog>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<userlog> call, Response<userlog> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   /* userdetails.setUserid(firebaseAuth.getUid());
                    userdetails.setEmail_(emailId.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainnewActivity.class));*/
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<userlog> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Successdd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

when I call "adduser_(userll)" method, I get a notification that "not Successdd".

Comment: Can you please tel us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: i use firebase in backend . backend developed by spring boot and using firebase. i test the api using postman and it work properly

Comment: If a task fails, there's a detailed error message. What does your `Log.e("error", t.getMessage());` log?

Comment: Ok, does `Log.e("error", t.getMessage());` print something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem related to retrofit, i think the problem because the response of the call come as null or empty

you can create NullConverterFactory.class :

```
 public class NullConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    
        @Override
        public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
            final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, type, annotations);
            return new Converter<ResponseBody, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object convert(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
                    if (body.contentLength() == 0) return null;
                    return delegate.convert(body);               
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

and add to the create of the retrofit

```
baseUrl(Config.URL+"/")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            // -----add here-------
            .addConverterFactory(new NullConverterFactory())
            //---------------------
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
```